# Count the frequency of a string in map in clojure

Tags: file-io, clojure, distinct-values

I am fairly new to clojure and just practicing some exam questions to prepare for a final exam.

I am trying to find the frequency of all the names is in a file. I read the file line by line and I save each string if it contains a specific keyword in a map. Since I do not want any repetitions, I am trying put distinct out in front of it, but I still keep getting the repeating elements.

```
(defn readFile []
  (map (fn [line] (clojure.string/split line #";"))
    (with-open [rdr (reader "C:/Users/Rohil's Computer/Desktop/textfile.txt")]
      (doseq [[idx line] (map-indexed vector(line-seq rdr))]

        (if(.contains line "2007")
          (if(.contains line "May")
            (if(not(.contains line "Batman"))
              (map save [(nth(clojure.string/split line #";")3 (nth(clojure.string/split line #";")19)])
              (distinct(map))
           )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Here is my sample output:
I want to get rid of the 2 iron man elements.

```
(May 2007 Spiderman)
Clojure2.clj:   
(March 2007 Iron man)
Clojure2.clj:   
(March 2007 Iron man)
Clojure2.clj:   
(April 2007 Captain America)
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Without giving it all away, here's a couple places to improve: 1. `distinct` takes a collection.  You are passing it the `map` function, so that's why you aren't getting what you hope for.  2. It's unlikely that the best answer to this involves nested `if` statements.  Try putting the values you want to test against into a vector then iterate that against your function. 3. Consider breaking your function out into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 3):

With Clojure a good approach is to break down what you need to accomplish a task into functions that are as simple as possible. Once you have written and tested those simple functions you will be able to combine them together. Often times, the simple function you need already exists, as is here the case with `frequencies`:

```
(frequencies ["foo" "bar" "foo" "quux" "foo"])
=> {"foo" 3, "bar" 1, "quux" 1}
```

So it sounds like all you need to do really is tokenize the input file and apply `frequencies` to the list of tokens.